# Berkeley Database > 5.3.x

Tags: ppa, berkeleydb

Berkely Database in the repos is inexplicably locked at 5.3.something. Current versions are north of 12. Might be north of 13 by now.

Is there a reason the repo never gets updated?

Is there a PPA where a version released in the past decade would be available?

According to the [changelog](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/berkeleydb/html/changelog_6_0.html), I need to get to at least 6.0.19

> New Features in 6.0.19 Fixed bugs when attempting to open non-DB files
>   as if they were databases. If encryption was active, an assertion
>   failure would occur. If encryption was not active, the error message
>   "BDB0178 Encrypted database: no encryption flag" would incorrectly
>   imply that a password was required. [#21408]

Thanks

Comment: Oracle license may be the problem.  Oracle products have a restrictive license that doesn't really let people ship it anymore.  That applies to the PPAs as well.  All Source downloads are now under Oracle's restricted license and a register-to-download wall so there's no way to get non-open-source variants of the library.   You'd have to download/install yourself and register an Oracle account to do this.  (Same reason SUN Java isn't released anymore)

Comment: Oregon State still has 6.2.23.  http://ftp.oregonstate.edu/.2/lfs-website/blfs/view/svn/server/db.html

Comment: Chances are that was the last 'open source' release.  Hence why that's listed/available.  However, older Ubuntu repository versions aren't likely to get a bump and newer versions are locked with the versions they have or the Oracle license blocking them,  If you want *newest* you need to download from Oracle and compile/install with their instructions